# Python - csv column restructuring

Tags: python, csv

I'm totally new to python.

I have a csv file.  Its structure is:

```
Ip, Tag, Sentence_id, scheme
#1, yes,      1,        1
#1, yes,      2,        2 
#2, no,       1,        1
#3  maybe,    3,        3
```

There are 100 sentence_id, a number of ips and 6 schemes (1-6).

Is there a way with python to restructure the csv so that it's output is a matrix of the following structure:

```
Ip,   scheme 1, scheme 2, scheme 3, sentence_id
#1      yes,      NA,          NA,      1
#1      NA,       yes,         NA,      2
#2      no,       NA,          NA,      1
#3      NA,       NA,         maybe,    3
```

I'm not sure if python is the "right" language to use for something like this.  I've been guided to either python or awk, but have no idea of either.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `csv.DictReader` to load the file into a list of dictionaries, then from that, find the maximum `scheme` value to build your output field names. For each row in the list, set the `scheme N` field to be equal to the value of the `Tag` column. Then we use `csv.DictWriter` to fill any missing values with `NA` where a key is not present, eg:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as fin, open('output.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    rows = list(csv.DictReader(fin, skipinitialspace=True))
    schemes = range(1, max(int(row['scheme']) for row in rows) + 1)
    fieldnames = ['Ip'] + ['scheme {}'.format(i) for i in schemes] + ['Sentence_id']
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore', restval='NA')
    csvout.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        row['scheme {}'.format(row['scheme'].strip())] = row['Tag']
        csvout.writerow(row)
```

This gives the following output given your example input:

```
Ip,scheme 1,scheme 2,scheme 3,Sentence_id
#1,yes,NA,NA,1
#1,NA,yes,NA,2
#2,no,NA,NA,1
#3,NA,NA,maybe,3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should read through the file line by line, reorder columns, etc.

Just replace in_filename, out_filename, NUM_SCHEMES, and the header with whatever you want.

```
from csv import reader, writer

with open("in_filename") as in_file, open("out_filename") as out_file:
    in_csv = csv.reader(in_file)
    out_csv = csv.writer(out_file)

    next(in_csv) # Skip header
    out_csv.writerow(["Ip", "scheme 1", "scheme 2", "scheme 3", "sentence_id"])

    for row in in_csv:
        ip, tag, sentence_id, scheme = row

        out_row = [ip]

        for i in range(NUM_SCHEMES):
            out_row.append(tag if i == scheme else "NA")

        out_row.append(sentence_id)

        out_csv.writerow(out_row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've got an error on line 9 "AttributeError: '_csv.writer' object has no attribute 'write_row'"

Comment: @user47467 looks like a typo - that should be `out_csv.writerow` (no underscore)

Comment: @user48467 Sorry, it should be writerow